# WINCE winform can't change size

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-ce

My winform can't change the size. The wince device is 480*764. I debugged and got a new size:

[image: debug]

But the size still unchanged. What happened?

Comment: FormBorderStyle should be set to sizable.

Comment: @AdrianStanculescu: Most C# developers are using the Compact Framework when working on Windows CE. If correct, the only border styles supported in the CF are None, FixedSingle and FixedDialog.

Comment: 2a4b8c2b: If you're using the Compact Framework version of .NET 2.0 or 3.5, please clarify that in the question or add a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your sizing code into the constructor not the `Load` event. Don't think that `FormBorderStyle` needs to be sizable (is this even supported in the .NET Compact Framework which I assume you are using?). Our forms have a style of `FixedDialog`. If you need to centre the form you can use this helper function which you call immediately after setting the size:

```
public static void SetFormPosition(Form frmChild)
{
    // Set the form position on the Windows CE panel
    if (frmChild != null)
    {
        // Get the size of the screen (should be 480x768)
        Rectangle rctScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

        // Now calculate the position of the form
        int nPosX = ((rctScreen.Width - frmChild.Width) / 2);
        int nPosY = ((rctScreen.Height - frmChild.Height) / 2);

        // Set the position
        frmChild.Location = new Point(nPosX, nPosY);
    }
}
```